# What is difference between a wrapper and a framework?

Tags: winapi, directx, class-design

What is the difference between a Win32 or DirectX wrapper and a Win32 or DirectX framework?

Comment: A framework (or "API") is usually specified in a particular language (e.g. C++).  A wrapper is used to "adapt" this API to languages or systems that it was not originally specified for.  In other words, it is usually a translation layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A wrapper is typically a family of functions that contain the function calls for a library or API like win32, DirectX, etc., in some sort of abstracted way to the end-user.  Many times they are customized so that the functions you call in the wrapper is not exactly the same as the original API, or some default parameters have been setup for you to make working with the API a bit easier.  Also in the specific instance of a language wrapper, the functionality has been embedded in the language's run-time API, and then exposed to the end-user.  For example, one could expose the win32 calls to a Python user by creating a C-library plug-in for python with the win32 API calls, and then creating a python library that may have customized python functions that call the win32 functions exposed by the C-library plugin. In this case the Python library "wraps" the native C-based win32 library.

A framework is like a wrapper, but in its most-typically used definition, it's a little different in that it works by creating some type of run-time environment that you create callbacks to plug into, so that when the frame-work wants to-do some task, you've written a function that is called for that task.  This is called the "Hollywood Principal" of programming, which basically says, "don't call us, we'll call you". So in working with this model, you create functions, register them with the frame-work, and your function is called when the frame-work needs to call it, and the framework passes its own internal parameters as your function arguments.  A good example is a GUI-framework, where you create callbacks for buttons and other events, and the GUI-framework calls those functions as it processes its runtime event-loop.

So I guess one way to think of the primary differentiation between the two is that wrappers tend to be static (i.e. exposing libraries and functions with customized function calls either that fill-in default values for you or translate them to a different language), whereas a framework tends to be dynamic (i.e. its a runtime system that you create callbacks for, and register it with the framework that are then called during some time of runtime event loop or kernel, etc., like a GUI toolkit).

Answer (score 0):

Wrappers tend to make it possible (oftentimes easier) to access complex systems, complex code or combinations of calls from multiple classes and so forth. For example, you may create a Facebook wrapper in C# or Java to interact with getting user data from the Facebook API, which has many REST-based functions which return JSON. A framework is a set of related objects, functions, and so forth to provide a particular functionality, or enhance a particular functionality, so you wouldn't use *either* a wrapper *or* framework. Oftentimes you'll use a both, using a wrapper to access a framework. This is especially true with legacy systems :)